# find and replace part of the string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace string  anything after `RIGHTS_TARGET=` with `www.domain.com`. How to find particular place replace from there?

```
<a href="/secured/login/rightsLogin?v=cls&amp;command=logout&amp;
  RIGHTS_TARGET=Replace Old url with new" style="" id="loginLink"><span></span>Sign Out</a>
```

Comment: what kind of attribute is that ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `regex` to replace the specific value.

```js
var a = $('a').attr('href', function(i, href) {
  return href.replace(/RIGHTS_TARGET=(.*)/.exec(href)[1], 'www.domain.com');
});

alert(a.attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/secured/login/rightsLogin?v=cls&amp;command=logout&amp;RIGHTS_TARGET=replace this part" style="" id="loginLink"><span></span>Sign Out</a>
```

Comment: Why downvoting without comment? What's the problem here?

Comment: @James123 your linked fiddle didn't include jQuery. This solution works as long as jQuery is included: https://jsfiddle.net/twernt/1et750xq/2/

Comment: The results replacing "RIGHTS_TARGET=". I need to replace anything after "RIGHTS_TARGET="

Comment: James123 You are right. I didn't understand the question correctly. I was updated my answer. Is that what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = $("#loginLink").attr("href");
var s = x.split("RIGHTS_TARGET=")[0]+"RIGHTS_TARGET=www.domain.com";
$("#loginLink").attr("href",s);
```

Comment: well? did you try this method?